# Responsive-loader chaining webpack

Tags: webpack

I'm a beginner webpack user. I wanted to optimize my images and later on 
serve different sizes of them depending on the viewport. So what I figured out at first was:

```
...

 {
            test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
            use: [{loader: 'file-loader',
            options:{
                name: '[name].[ext]',
                outputPath: '/imgs',
                publicPath: '/imgs'
            }}, {
                loader: "url-loader",
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    fallback: 'responsive-loader'
                }},
                "image-webpack-loader"
            ]
        },
...
```

What I was thinking is:

- optimize my image with 'image-wbpack-loader
- if optimized version of it is less than 10k bits than make it 64base encoded
- if not than load it with 'responsive-loader'
- and at the end push all images that 'responsive-loader' generates to the /imgs directory

The only problem is that it doesn't work.
I was trying to find some other way of doing this and I found 'imagemin-webpack-plugin'. I tried to use it by writing:

```
 new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {from: './src/imgs', to: './imgs'}
    ]),
 new ImageminPlugin({
      { test: 'imgs/**'}
    }}),
```

It worked as expected. Copied and optimized my all images. But I'm now unable to use any loader's operations on them because they are already in dist directory. 
Is there any way to achieve the effect I want? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Responsive-loader has the 'quality' option that lets me define how much I want to optimize my images. No other plugins are necessary.